# wordpress get list of all header menu items

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I have a Wordpress site. On one of the pages i want to show a list of items that are in the header. I dont really want to show the header itself.

For example i have this setup in wordpress theme for header by going to `wp-admin->Appreance->Header->Menu-TopMenu`

```
Home | About | Contact
```

Now in one of the templates i want to get an array of these three items as

```
{Home, About, Contact}
```

What Wordpress method is available to fetch this?

Looking at the default header.php i see this code but dont really understand how i get what i need from it.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'top',
    'menu_id'        => 'top-menu',
) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear. If you want to display a separate menu on a particular page you can have two options. For example if you want to display a different menu on `about` page.

1. In your **header.php.**

   `if(is_page('about')) { //about is the slug of the page.
      wp_nav_menu( array(
       'menu' => 'about' //Here about is the name or slug of the menu
   ) );
   } else { // All other pages we can display the default menu.
      wp_nav_menu( array(
       'theme_location' => 'top',
       'menu_id'        => 'top-menu',
   ) );
   }`
2. If you want to display an entirely different header on `about` page.

Create a new header file named `header-about.php` where about is the slug of the about page. Or you can use the page id as well and put the header content needed for that about page. All other pages will load the default `header.php` file.

Please refer to these codex functions

1. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/
2. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

Comment: Actually in the about page I want to know the options of the menu. I want to process this data for some custom behavior. The about page does even need to have a top menu. I want to know what the admin has configured for the header

Comment: What you mean by options? You can get menu items as php Array by using this function `wp_get_nav_menu_items`
Or if you want some custom html to be applied to your menu you must extend and create a 
`WP_nav_walker`. Normally these are the functions applied on a menu.